# creating dynamic array in a dynamic javascript object (key/value pair)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've thought that this is how the data will look for every query operation having a unique id (which is 1 & 2 in below example).

```
var finalData = {
    queryData: {
        "1": { // here "1" will be the auto-incrementing query operation id generated from somewhere
            jiraList: ["abc-123", "bcd-234"],
            jiraDetail: [
                {
                    jiraKey: "abc-123",
                    status: "Closed"
                },
                {
                    jiraKey: "bcd-234",
                    status: "Open"
                }
            ]
        },
        "2": {
            jiraList: ["xyz-987", "wxy-876"],
            jiraDetail: [
                {
                    jiraKey: "xyz-987",
                    status: "Open"
                },
                {
                    jiraKey: "wxy-876",
                    status: "Closed"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

I've a function which accepts the query's unique id & jira List (which is already an array):

```
var addJiraList = function (key, jiraList) {
    // sample params will be key: 1, jiraList: ['abc-123', 'bcd-234']
    finalData.queryData[key] = {jiraList: jiraList};
};
```

So the above function creates a key value pair in `finalData.queryData` if not present, and if present, it'll add/update `jiraList` with required values to it. This works.

I've another function which accepts the query's unique id & a single jiraDetail which is:

```
var addJiraData = function (queryKey, extractedData) {
    // sample params will be queryKey: 1, extractedData: { jiraKey: "abc-123", status: "Closed" }
    finalData.queryData[queryKey]["jiraDetail"].push(extractedData);
};
```

I want to push the `extractedData` coming as parameter in the array `finalData.queryData.2.jiraDetail`.

Now the problem is that `finalData.queryData.<queryId>` is dynamic & `jiraDetail` is an array inside it. So for the first time if `queryKey is 1` & `extractedData is {something}`, how would I add one item `extractedData` into an array (jiraDetail) of `queryKey` which is not even created.

At present it is throwing `finalData.queryData[queryKey] is undefined` error which is valid as I cannot add inside an object which is not yet created.

Solution in my mind is to check if `finalData.queryData[queryKey] is undefined` and if it is undefined then first create the object with empty `jiraDetail` array in it so that the following line will not throw undefined error.

```
finalData.queryData[queryKey]["jiraDetail"].push(extractedData);
```

There must be something better that can be done which I'm at present unable to think & search. I want to know how would you handle this situation?

Here's the link of the file which will be updated based on the answer that I'll get here.

https://github.com/sunilrebel/spann-jira/blob/master/lib/storageSystem.js

Comment: You should be checking for the keys existence either way - it's not a big deal... not sure why that's a problem?

Comment: It's not a problem actually, just confirming that if the function is called thousand times, checking every time existence is a big deal or not. Because it'll actually create space once & rest time it'll skip the `if` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed need to check if the key is present in `finalData.queryData` and if not create. Look at this solution:

```
var addJiraData = function (queryKey, extractedData) {
    if (!finalData.queryData[queryKey] || !finalData.queryData[queryKey]["jiraDetail"])
    {
        //one of the objects isn't present, let's create it.
        !finalData.queryData[queryKey] ? addJiraList(queryKey, []) : null; //add missing queryKey and empty array as jiraList.
        finalData.queryData[queryKey]["jiraDetail"] = []; //create empty jiraDetail array.
    }
    //then fill it with data, since it is available now.
    finalData.queryData[queryKey]["jiraDetail"].push(extractedData);
};
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. That's exactly what I thought. Seems checking every time is not a big deal even if the function is called thousand of times.

Comment: Data consistency is in this case more important. The function isn't too heavy, so that should not effect performance.